# Changing Text message limit

Tags: sms, backup

I want to change my text message limit to a smaller size (default 200 msgs per conversation) so that it will be easy to scroll and read messages. But I don't want to lose previous messages. Can I start a new conversation thread with the same contact?

Also, is there a method that will allow me to backup my messages in a text or HTML file? Where are the messages stored (can I just copy to my laptop)? I have not rooted my phone yet. I use a SMS backup+ application which saves in Gmail as separate entries which is not desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [SMS Backup & Restore](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&feature=search_result) which backups your text messages to an XML file on your SD card (does not require root). This way at least you can safely lower the message limit and still save your messages somewhere.

I'm not aware of any way to lower the limit without the Messaging application automatically deleting old messages - in the stock messaging app anyway.